# ndk-build with Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, ndk-build

Rebuild my old C++ module on Lollipop with ndk-build throws lost of "not defined in this scope" errors regarding to KEY_SOFT1, KEY_SOFT2, KEY_CENTER, KEY_END. Which never happen on Android 4. What was wrong?

**My Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := AndroidJNI

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := [C++ source files]

LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -D_SCREENSHOT -D_ANDROID5 -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H

LOCAL_CXXFLAGS  := -D_SCREENSHOT -D_ANDROID5
```

**My Application.mk**

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
STLPORT_FORCE_REBUILD := true
APP_ABI := armeabi x86
```

**UPDATE**

Digging into android-ndk\platforms folder, under android-15\input.h. I found that those keys are defined as:

```
#define KEY_STAR 227
#define KEY_SHARP 228
#define KEY_SOFT1 229
#define KEY_SOFT2 230
#define KEY_SEND 231
#define KEY_CENTER 232
```

But under android-21\input.h, they are gone !? Where did they all go?